# Locked Layer/Composition background

Tags: layers, adobe-after-effects, composition

I'd like to know how can I change the color purple background and expand it. I've downloaded a template for an intro and the only thing I seem to have trouble with is this one. I already looked into the layers and all of the composition background yet I can't find the purple background.
Thank you in advance 
[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell without looking into what the nested compositions contains. You could start by looking into the bottom [Text HERE] layer (double-click on it) and trace backwards that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since we won't be able to answer without looking at this specific file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be that it is a purple background but a layer or object with a different blend mode.